# symfony Twig_Error_Runtime, no authentication token

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig, token

I try to resolve an error without success for few days. I really don't know where to search anymore.

My error is :

```
[2015-09-27 17:59:15] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /css/"" at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1985 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /css/\" at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1985, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1011)"} []
[2015-09-27 17:59:17] request.ERROR: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.") in "::navbar.html.twig" at line 72.) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /css/\" at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1985, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1011)"} []
```

The only thing i have on my navbar at line 72 is : {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

The navbar is on every pages and the pages are accessible with and without account.

On the website, i have sometimes a blank page with only the payement form on it. I don't know yet if it is because of this error, bug when i clear the cache, the home page become normal again.

Please i really need help because i can't deliver the website with this error

EDIT:

Didn't fixed the error, now i get :

```
[2015-09-28 05:13:44] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /newpassword.php"" at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1985 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /newpassword.php\" at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1985, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1011)"} []
[2015-09-28 05:13:47] request.ERROR: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.") in "::navbar.html.twig" at line 72.) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /newpassword.php\" at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1985, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/clickandi/www/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1011)"} []
```

Very weird because i don't have any newpassword.php in my project

At line 72 i have : {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

EDIT2:

Here is my navbar template :

```
<div class="isConnexion">
</div>

<div class="forConnexion">
  <div class="closeForConnexion">
    <img src="{{asset('img/crossClose.png')}}" alt="">
  </div>
  <h2>CONNEXION</h2>
  <div class="container-modal">
  </div>
  <div class="mdpOublie">
    <p><a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}">Mot de passe oublié ?</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="facebookLogin">
    <h2>Se connecter avec facebook</h2>
  </div> -->
  <a href="{{ path('user_register') }}"><div class="inscrivezVous">
    <h2>INSCRIVEZ VOUS</h2>
  </div></a>
</div>

<div class="forParrainage">

  <h2>Saisissez votre code</h2>
  <p>Notre système de parrainage unique vous permet d’offrir gratuitement un verre à un ami. Pour cela il vous suffit de renseigner le code que le bar partenaire de click and cheers vous a donné avec votre addition.</p>

  <div class="champsParrainagePopUPHeader">
    <p>Votre code</p>

    <input type="text" class="codeValue" placeholder="Ex: 435e5d" maxlength="6">
  </div>

  <button class="ticketVerreValidate">Valider</button>

</div>

<div class="popupsponsorship completionAdresse">
  <h2>On lui offre quand ?</h2>
  <div id="datepicker"></div>
  <input type="text" id="datepickerInput" hidden>
  <input type="text" id="codeInput" hidden>
</div>

<div class="emailsponsorship" style="display:none;">
  <h2>Qui sera l'élu(e) ?</h2>
  <p>Notre système de parrainage unique vous permet d'offrir un verre gratuitement à un ami.</p>
  <p>Il ne vous reste donc plus qu'à choisir l'ami en question.</p> 
  <br/>
  <p>Invitez le par email</p>
  <input id="mailToSend" type="email" placeholder="Tapez ici son adresse e-mail">
  <!--<br/>
  <br/>
  <p>Invitez le par facebook messenger</p>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Tapez ici son Prénom et Nom">-->
  <br/>
  <button id="senddrink">Valider</button>
</div>

<nav class="menuNav">
    <button class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg menu__handle">
        <span>Menu</span>
    </button>
    <div class="contentLogo">
        <a href="{{ path('home') }}">
            <img src="{{asset('img/LogoClickandcheers.svg')}}" alt="Click and Cheers">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuMob">


        <div class="administration">
            {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                <div class="profileUserNav">
                  <img class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" src="{{asset('img/imgProfilBasic.png')}}">
                  {% if is_granted('ROLE_BARMAN') and not is_granted('ROLE_BIGBOSS') %}
                    <p>Bonjour <span class="nameInHeader">{{ app.user.getUsername()}}</span> </p>
                  {% else %}
                    <p>Bonjour <span class="nameInHeader">{{ app.user.firstname}}</span> </p>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                      <img src="{{asset('img/pictoHeader/reservation.svg')}}">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul>
                    {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_BIGBOSS') or is_granted('ROLE_BARMAN') %}
                        <li>
                            {% render url('navigation') %}
                            <a href="{{ path('barman_register') }}"><p>Ajouter un barman</p></a>
                            {% if is_granted('ROLE_BIGBOSS') %}
                              <a href="{{ path('bar_new') }}"><p>Créer un bar</p></a>
                              <a href="{{ path('bars_list') }}"><p>Mes bars</p></a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </li>
                        <li class="navToggleBtn logout"><a href="#" class="displayMore"><p>Afficher plus</p></a></li>
                        <li class="navToggle navLine"><div class="lisere"></div></li>
                        <li class="navToggle"><a class="mesReservation" href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mes réservations</p></a></li>
                        <li class="navToggle"><a class="mesParrainage" href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mes parrainages</p></a></li>
                        <li class="navToggle"><a class="monCompte" href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mon compte</p></a></li>
                        <li class="navToggle hidden"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mes points</p></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a class="mesReservation" href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mes réservations</p></a></li>
                        <li><a class="mesParrainage" href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mes parrainages</p></a></li>
                        <li><a class="monCompte" href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mon compte</p></a></li>
                        <li class="navToggle hidden"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}"><p>Mes points</p></a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                    <li class="logout"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}"><p>Déconnexion</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            {% else %}
                <div class="connexionInscription">
                    <p class="animConnexion">Connexion</p>
                    <p><a href="{{ path('user_register') }}">Inscription</a></p>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="contentNav">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg noPadding">
                    {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                        {% if is_granted('ROLE_BARMAN') and not is_granted('ROLE_BIGBOSS') %}
                          <p>Bonjour <span class="nameInHeader">{{ app.user.getUsername()}}</span> </p>
                        {% else %}
                          <p>Bonjour <span class="nameInHeader">{{ app.user.firstname}}</span> </p>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% else %}
                        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg noPadding">
                            <p class="leftMobile animConnexion">Connexion</p>
                            <p class="leftMobile"><a href="{{ path('user_register') }}">Inscription</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="separationHeader"></div>
                     {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 noPadding">
                        <p class="leftMobile"><a class="trouverBar" href="{{ path('bars') }}">Trouver un bar</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 noPadding">
                        <p class="leftMobile"><a class="hasard" href="{{ path('randomBar') }}">Au hasard</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 noPadding">
                        <p class="leftMobile"><a class="parrainage" href="#">Parrainage</a></p>
                    </div>

                    {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="separationHeader"></div>
                    {% if is_granted('ROLE_BIGBOSS') or is_granted('ROLE_BARMAN') %}

                        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg noPadding">
                          <p class="leftMobile"><a href="{{ path('barman_register') }}">Ajouter un barman</a></p>

                        {% if is_granted('ROLE_BIGBOSS') %}

                            <p class="leftMobile"><a href="{{ path('bar_new') }}">Créer un bar</a></p>
                            <p class="leftMobile"><a href="{{ path('bars_list') }}">Mes bars</a></p>

                        {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="separationHeader"></div>
                      {% endif %}
                      <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg noPadding">

                        <p class="leftMobile mesReservation"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}">Mes réservations</a></p>

                        <p class="leftMobile mesParrainage"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}">Mes parrainages</a></p>

                        <p class="leftMobile monCompte"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}">Mon compte</a></p>

                        <p class="leftMobile"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}">Mes points</a></p>

                        <p class="logout"><a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Déconnexion</a></p>
                      </div>

                      {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
function souris(event)
{
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  //alert('Vous avez cliqué au point de coordonnés: ' + x + ', ' + y );
}</script>
```

Comment: Show us `navbar.html.twig`

Comment: Just updated my post ;)

Comment: Where's it line 72? Have you deleted the cache on production?

Comment: The line 72 is "{% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}" just after my class administration. And yes, i deleted my prod cache after changing the code

Comment: What return `app.user`? (`{{ dump(app.user) }}`)

Comment: If i m not connected, it return NULL, else it return my user object

Comment: How can return `NULL` if `is_granted` is executed? _What is the value of app.user_?

Comment: I dumped my app.user before the is_granted, to see both connected users and not connected user, this is why i can have NULL when not logged

Comment: So you see the user's object in the 404 error page?

Comment: Sorry, but i think there is a misunderstood. I'm not talking about 404 or any other error page. It s on my home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [Avoiding Exceptions when Using Security Functions in Error Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#avoiding-exceptions-when-using-security-functions-in-error-templates) in the Symfony documentation, that say:

> One of the common pitfalls when designing custom error pages is to use the is_granted() function in the error template [...] The cause of this problem is that routing is done before security. If a 404 error occurs, the security layer isn't loaded and thus, the is_granted() function is undefined.

This is what happen to you. The solution of this problem is in the documentation.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your response.
Will do that and check if it fix the errors